# Cron job is working on localhost but not on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cron, vercel

With `vercel dev` I can run the following code, but when I run on Vercel (https:/avercelurl/api/cron) I receive `{"success":true}` but `runTest` function doesn't run at all.

What can be the problem with my code? Or how can I debug it on Vercel?

```
const WebPageTest = require("webpagetest");
const { google } = require('googleapis');

export default function handler(req, res) {
    const wpt = new WebPageTest("www.webpagetest.org", process.env.WEBPAGETEST_API_KEY);
    const finalResults = [];

    // Your list of URLs to test
    let urls = [
        "https://somedomain.com",
        "https://anotherdomain.com"
    ];

    let options = {
        firstViewOnly: true,
        location: "Dulles:Chrome",
        pollResults: 5,
        timeout: 240,
        lighthouse: 1
    };

    const runTest = (wpt, url, options) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`Submitting test for ${url}...`);
            
            wpt.runTest(url, options, async (err, result) => {
            try {
                if (result) {
                return resolve(result);
                } else {
                return reject(err);
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.info(e);
            }
            });
        });
    };

    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: "keyfile.json", //the key file
        //url to spreadsheets API
        scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", 
    });

    Promise.all(
        urls.map(async (url) => {
            try {
                //Auth client Object
                const authClientObject = await auth.getClient();
                
                //Google sheets instance
                const googleSheetsInstance = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: authClientObject });

                // spreadsheet id
                const spreadsheetId = process.env.GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_ID;

                // Get metadata about spreadsheet
                const sheetInfo = await googleSheetsInstance.spreadsheets.get({
                    auth,
                    spreadsheetId
                });
                
                await runTest(wpt, url, options).then(async (result) => {
                    if (result.data) {
                        //Read from the spreadsheet
                        const readData = await googleSheetsInstance.spreadsheets.values.get({
                            auth, //auth object
                            spreadsheetId, // spreadsheet id
                            range: "Sheet1!A:A", //range of cells to read from.
                        })

                        // console.log(`https://www.webpagetest.org/jsonResult.php?test=${result.data.id}&pretty=1`);

                        //write data into the google sheets
                        await googleSheetsInstance.spreadsheets.values.append({
                            auth, //auth object
                            spreadsheetId, //spreadsheet id
                            range: "Sheet1!A:A", //sheet name and range of cells
                            valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED", // The information will be passed according to what the usere passes in as date, number or text
                            resource: {
                                values: [[`https://www.webpagetest.org/jsonResult.php?test=${result.data.id}&pretty=1`]]
                            },
                        }).then((resp) => {
                            
                        });
                        
                        return;
                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        })
    ).then(() => {
        // console.info(finalResults);
    });

    res.status(200).json({ success: true });
};
```

If I move `res.status(200).json({ success: true });` up 2 rows into `then()` it works, but also times out, so it doesn't finish.

Comment: Is this deployed as a Serverless Function or Edge Function? I think Serverless Functions will end the process after it returns a response (I thought there was documentation that explicitly stated this but can't find it, only pulling this from memory and inferring from documentation on [Serverless Function timeouts](https://vercel.com/docs/limits/overview#serverless-function-execution-timeout) where it says streaming responses are only supported in Edge Functions).

Comment: Regardless of using Serverless or Edge Function, if you're hitting timeouts you need to make your task smaller or quicker or both. Just from the code you've provided in your question and making various assumptions (which may be wrong), I'd ask the following questions back to you: (1) Do you need one function invocation to process multiple URLs or can you build a queue to have one function invocation for each URL? (2) There's lots of stuff in the `map` loop, can anything there be done once and shared across loop iterations? For example, can you auth once or read the spreadsheet once?

Comment: If you really can't change the code, then Vercel may not be a suitable platform. You'll probably need to go lower level with a service like AWS Lambda that may allow configuration for your needs.

Comment: You are not awaiting any of the promises you create in your request handler, thus the last `res.status(200).json({ success: true });` is immediately executed and returns the result to the client.